# left outer joining three tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables like shown below:

[image]

And i am trying to get output like below:

[image]

Here is what i have tried till now

```
    SELECT table1.tb1_a,
CASE WHEN table3.tb3_a IS NOT NULL THEN
    tb3_b
    ELSE 'No city for him yet'
END AS 'City'
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON
    table1.tb1_a = table2.tb2_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON
    table2.tb2_a = table3.tb3_a
WHERE table3.tb3_a IN
    (

    )
```

And now i am struggling on how to select the maximum value of the tb3_a column

Comment: I think what may confuse people here is that I think you actually want the maximum value of `tb2_b` and then join that to `tb3_a`.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your current attempt.  You compare tb2_a with tb3_a.  It looks like you should be comparing tb2_b with tb3_a.

Comment: @Walter - you're right see my example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
SELECT t1.tb1_a, COALESCE(t3.tb3_a, 'No city for him yet') AS City
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(tb2_b) AS tb2_b, tb2_a
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY tb2_a
) t2 ON (t2.tb2_a = t1.tb1_a)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t3.tb3_a = t3.tb2_b);
```

The key point is the in-line view in the middle where we create a kind of virtual table that contains the maximum `tb2_b` value for each `tb2_a`. We can then join to this to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
select tb1_a, nvl(max(city), 'no city for him yet') thecity
from etc
group by tbl_a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this with analytic functions.  Here is how:

```
SELECT tb1_a, coalesce(tb3_b, 'No city for him yet') as City
from (select table1.tb1_a, tb3_b,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by table1.tbl1_a order by tb3_a desc) as seqnum
      FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
           table2
           ON table1.tb1_a = table2.tb2_a LEFT OUTER JOIN
           table3
           ON table2.tb2_a = table3.tb3_a
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This uses `row_number()` to determine the last entry in table3.  This is chosen by the `where seqnum = 1` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ba1c/12

```
SELECT table1.tb1_a,
       CASE WHEN table3.tb3_a IS NOT NULL THEN tb3_b
            ELSE 'No city for him yet'
       END AS City,
table2.*, table3.*
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON    table1.tb1_a = table2.tb2_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON    table2.tb2_b = table3.tb3_a
where tb2_b = (select max(tb2_b) 
                 from table2 t22 
                where t22.tb2_a = tb1_a)
or    tb2_b is null
order by 1
```

I think the where clause explains itself

Comment: This is marvelous..I understood the where i was doing wrong quickly.. Thanks a ton to prepare the tables and everything on sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Juergen, whilst your query may return the correct results, having a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause can get very expensive as the subquery must be executed once for each row returned by the result set.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope you help

```
with table_1 as
 (select 10 as tb1_a, 'John' as tb1_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 20 as tb1_a, 'John1' as tb1_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 30 as tb1_a, 'John2' as tb1_b from dual),
table_2 as
 (select 10 as tb2_a, 100 as tb2_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 10 as tb2_a, 1000 as tb2_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 10 as tb2_a, 10000 as tb2_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 20 as tb2_a, 200 as tb2_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 20 as tb2_a, 2000 as tb2_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 20 as tb2_a, 20000 as tb2_b from dual),
table_3 as
 (select 100 as tb3_a, 'City1' as tb3_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 1000 as tb3_a, 'City10' as tb3_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 10000 as tb3_a, 'City100' as tb3_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 200 as tb3_a, 'City2' as tb3_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 2000 as tb3_a, 'City20' as tb3_b
    from dual
  union all
  select 20000 as tb3_a, 'City200' as tb3_b from dual)

select user_id, city
  from (select u.tb1_a as user_id,
               nvl(c.tb3_b, 'No city') as city,
               rank() over(partition by u.tb1_a order by tb3_a) as city_rank
          from table_1 u, table_2 u_c, table_3 c
         where u.tb1_a = u_c.tb2_a(+)
           and u_c.tb2_b = c.tb3_a(+)) t1
 where city_rank = 1
```